# In Spring native: Generation of HibernateProxy instances at runtime is not allowed when the configured BytecodeProvider

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, boot, graalvm

I have a User entity that has Lazy relations

```
 @JoinTable(name = "user_identities", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_identity_id")})
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Identity> identities;

    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

I execute hibernate

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.identities i JOIN FETCH u.roles r WHERE i.sub = :sub AND i.issuer = :issuer")
Optional<User> findByIdentitySubAndIssuer(String sub, String issuer);
```

In jvm mode (not native) everything works fine, but in native image, i am getting the following error:

*Generation of HibernateProxy instances at runtime is not allowed when the configured BytecodeProvider is 'none'; your model requires a more advanced BytecodeProvider to be enabled..*

I am using spring boot 3.1.0

Hibernate version 6.2.2 Final

I was trying to enable hibernate enhancer, adding to properties
jpa:
properties:
hibernate:
enhancer:
enable: true

which resulted in another exception on application startup in native mode
*Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Default-resolver threw exception*
*Could not instantiate named strategy class [org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.ColumnOrderingStrategyStandard]*

UPDATE:
with
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.7'
and
id 'org.hibernate.orm' version "6.1.7.Final

still getting
In Spring native: Generation of HibernateProxy instances at runtime is not allowed when the configured BytecodeProvider

Please help.
tnx

Comment: What version of Spring Native?

Comment: id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.20'
 id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'

Answer (score 3):

As described in [this Spring issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29779), you need to provide bytecode enhancement at build time through *hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin*

gradle

```
plugins {
    id "org.hibernate.orm" version "<version-to-use>"
}

hibernate {
    enhancement {
        lazyInitialization true
    }
}
```

maven

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>$currentHibernateVersion</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Also consider that in latest Hibernate version 6.2, *enableLazyInitialization* param used in the plugin has been deprecated and enabled by default :
[HHH-15641](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15641)

For more information about bytecode enhancement see [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#tooling-enhancement)